# Django - deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher upon running python manage.py runserver

Tags: django, linux, python-3.9

I am running a linux red hat environment from AWS.

I have followed every instruction for upgrading sqlite3 to the "latest" version.

I am running python 3.9.2 (and have recompiled it with `LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./configure`) and django version 4.

I have set up a virtual environment to install and run django. I have changed the activate script to include `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"`

Upon running `python manage.py runserver`, I get the error `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher`. I have opened the file `/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py` (where the error occurs) and right after the line with the error have include a print statement:

```
print("**************************\n" +
    str(Database.sqlite_version) +
    "\n" + str(Database.sqlite_version_info) +
    "\n**************************")
```

which retruns:

```
**************************
3.28.0
(3, 28, 0)
**************************
**************************
3.28.0
(3, 28, 0)
**************************
```

Please let me know what additional information is needed. I have searched up and down the `stack` and can't find the right solution to `pop` this one off.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Here is the traceback:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/asyncio.py", 21 in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 210, in get_new_connection
    create_deterministic_function('django_date_extract', 2, _sqlite_datetime_extract)
sqlite3.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python/3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/python39/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 126, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connectsion[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/djanog/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 210, in get_new_connection
    create_deterministic_function('django_date_extract', 2, _sqlite_datetime_extract)
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I came across the same issue in my linux Centos7+python3.9.6+Django3.2.5.
Althougt the sqlite3 is updated to the lastest version. It seems that this is useless. A kind of solution is changing the database from sqlite3 to pysqlite3.
After acticate the virtualenv, install pysqlite

```
pip3 install pysqlite3
pip3 install pysqlite3-binary
```

and change db in base.py

```
vim python3.9.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py

# from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database # annotation
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database # import pysqlite3
```

restart django server and it works.

Comment: it`s not fundamental answer but work so nice. thanks

Comment: got this error when running "pip3 install pysqlite3" -> fatal error C1083: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory

Comment: @TomásGomezPizarro that could be a problem with pip or your python interpreter. You might have to delete and reinstall python

Comment: The latest release of pysqlite3-binary as of Jan 17 2024 (pysqlite3-binary 0.5.2.post3) seems to break this fix. (Getting `deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher` from pysqlite3 now) 

The resolution in this case is to `pip3 install pysqlite3-binary==0.5.2.post2`

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I have got the same problem as yours. when I tried to deploy on **Elastic Beanstalk**.
In my case used **Python 3.8** when I initialized **EB CLI** like this:

```
eb init -p python-3.8 django-project ⛔
```

and that not a good python version to run it on 64bit Amazon Linux 2 (default). change to python-3.7

```
eb init -p python-3.7 django-project ✅
```

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to keep python updated.

Comment: If you're on Django 4 this answer will not work (Python 3.8+ required)

Answer (score 5):

It can be solved by recompiling python3 with the correct environment. Below are the commands for recompiling python3.

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/PATH_TO_SQLITE/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/PATH_TO_SQLITE/include 
export LD_RUN_PATH=/PATH_TO_SQLITE/lib
./configure --prefix=/PATH_FOR_PYTHON 
make
make install
```

Then a check can be done in python by the below commands

```
import sqlite3 
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') 
conn.create_function('f', 2, lambda *args: None, deterministic=True)
```

Comment: Its going to be a while before I can test this, so I am going to upvote, because this seems like the intuitive answer, though I mentioned in the post that I did recompile, I probably didn't export the variables before doing so, or include the path to Python.

Comment: Confirming this is the perfect solution for me. (CentOS 7, manually updated: python3.9, sqlite3.40). Because, most of the solutions online for this problem mentions set LD_RUN_PATH to statically link sqlite3, but no one mentions you have to include header files using C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH. thank you. @Jaebak Kim

Answer (score 2):

The best I can figure at the moment is to go into `/home/ec2-user/django/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py`, change the function variable `deterministic=True` in `get_new_connection()` to `deterministic=False`...

This will remove the error, but seems like a super cheaty solution. If anyone has a better fix, please let me know.

Comment: this actually works. gosh. i stuck on this for days... i know it's sketchy, but still... i'll do more research. all of my focus was on the wrong direction. i thought it was the sqlite3 version.

Comment: @user1835157 Well, there are definitely problems with this. 1. You can't upgrade django without having to redo this. 2. I don't know if it breaks the django models, but it very much may. 3. If the django models are broken, you probably can't use `celery` (a common library with django). 4. Recompiling python after you install sqlite3 seems like it should work and be objectively best -> @JaebakKim's answer.

Comment: thanks again for the heads up. i'm only doing this as learning and testing. after i tried you solution, i kept trying other ways. you're right, recompiling with correct including and linking options is the RIGHT way i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Using PostgreSQL is a good choice as it does support python 3.8 and solves this error. Also as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896814/syncing-local-and-elastic-beanstalk-database) is explained that it is better to use postgreSQL for production. Having said that I recommend this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#elastic-beanstalk-vs-ec2) that teaches how to run postgres on eb. Despite it is a bit outdated it was for me very useful.

Comment: EB was mentioned in another answer, but glad you got it to work.

Answer (score -3):

安装 pip3 install pysqlite3
打开文件/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py，找到 from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database 注释它，替换为from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database

vim /u01/apps/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/_functions.py  将deterministic=True中的函数变量get_new_connection()更改为deterministic=False ..

然后

vim /u01/apps/python3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py# def ： check_database_version_supported  里面的方法注释掉 写上pass

如：
def check_database_version_supported(self):
pass
"""
Raise an error if the database version isn't supported by this
version of Django.
"""

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yah. we are going to need you to clarify your answer, and try to fix your formatting.