# Django to AWS deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

Tags: python, django, sqlite, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my AWS application but am receiving an error when I navigate to its EC instance URL:

> deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

[image]

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380006/django-deterministic-true-requires-sqlite-3-8-3-or-higher-upon-running-python), but when I run `eb deploy` and `eb ssh` and `vi /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py`, the file still says :

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
```

rather than :

```
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
```

However, in "/var/app/current/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" it correctly says :

```
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I wasn't able to get mysql working. Instead, I opted to migrate to an aws Postgres instance. It's working fine now.