# problem with SQLite when deploying Django Website on AWS, cant properly install pysqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, backend

`I have made Django blog. I encountered this error after deploy using Elastic Beanstalk when trying to visit my website on AWS:

```
Django - deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher upon running python manage.py runserver
```

So I found this solution:

[Django - deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher upon running python manage.py runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380006/django-deterministic-true-requires-sqlite-3-8-3-or-higher-upon-running-python)

So i understand it like this:

1. In ubuntu terminal i type : `sudo apt install python3.10-venv` to install envirement
2. Then in my Django project in Visual Studio i type `python3 -m venv django_my_site` to create virtual env
3. Now i click "+" to open this env and type `pip3 install pysqlite3'` and `'pip3 install pysqlite3-binary`
4. After that i type `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`
   and i get requirements.txt file which looks like that:

```
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.1.4
Pillow==9.3.0
pysqlite3==0.5.0
pysqlite3-binary==0.5.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
```

Now AWS have problem with installing pysqlite3.
How to properly install pysqlite3 on AWS?
AWS log:

```
Encountered error while trying to install package.
pysqlite3`
    
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
      
src/blob.h:4:10: fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
#include "sqlite3.h"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

LINK TO MY REPOSITORY:

https://github.com/Stanotech/my_site.git

Comment: Hello! The linked repository no longer exists - did you resolve this yourself already? If so, feel free to self-answer and Accept it.

Comment: now it work. Current commit is current :)

Answer (score 1):

The error here appears to stem from the lack of the development headers for `sqlite` compilation in the AWS environment.

In your ubuntu environment, the development headers likely already exist, and you can confirm that they do with something like:

```bash
$ dpkg -l | grep sqlite
ii  libsqlite3-0:amd64                 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.3                 amd64        SQLite 3 shared library
ii  libsqlite3-dev:amd64               3.31.1-4ubuntu0.3                 amd64        SQLite 3 development files
```

Since the author of `pysqlite3` has provided both the source distribution and a precompiled binary version, you should only add one to the requirements file you intend to ship to Elastic Beanstalk - `pysqlite-binary` (https://pypi.org/project/pysqlite-binary/)

Then you should be able to use it via `import pysqlite3`

Comment: you were right. I add to requirements.tht just:
pysqlite3-binary==0.5.0

I also added in settings.py: 

__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')

before DATABASES =

Answer (score 0):

As mike said:

I add to requirements.tht just:

```
pysqlite3-binary==0.5.0
```

I also added in settings.py:

```
__import__('pysqlite3')
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
```

before:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```