# AWS App Runner and Django - deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, sqlite, amazon-app-runner

I'm using AWS App Runner to deploy a django web app, following this guide [Deploy and scale Django applications on AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/containers/deploy-and-scale-django-applications-on-aws-app-runner/). I have no problems deploying, but when I access a page, I'm getting the following error during template rendering.

[deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzrYR.png)

I searched for this error and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380006/django-deterministic-true-requires-sqlite-3-8-3-or-higher-upon-running-python), but I don't know how to apply it to AWS App Runner.

Can anyone help me with this or have any other solutions to try?

Comment: That guide you linked is using RDS PosgreSQL for the database, not SQLite. SQLite will not work in the scalable App Runner environment you are deploying to, since each instance of your app container would get an entirely separate, and empty, new database.

Comment: Thanks, I will give up SQLite and try to use another db

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue when running django over App Runner.
This issue is due to the sqlite3 database engine in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Instead of this use sql engine. Obviously you shouldn't use db.sqlite.3 file for database. For that, I have tried to install 'mysqlclient' but got below error.
"Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name. Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually". I have tried many solutions but none worked for me. Finally, instead of mysqlclient, I have used 'pymysql' library.

```
pip install pymysql
```

settings.py includes,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<database-name>',
        'USER': '<database-user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<database-password>',
        'HOST': '<database-host>',
        'PORT': '<database-port>',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    }
}
```

And add below lines in init.py file in project root directory (where settings.py file located)

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

For database you can use RDS or any publicly accessible database.
Deploy App Runner and look for the logs .